# looking to Work around the 403 error with php script

Tags: javascript, php

I have been using JavaScript to retrieve my images from a directory and on local-host this works just fine but now I am running it on a remote sever I get the 403 Forbidden Error, I know why this is but I am looking for a way around it, keeping my Java functioning much the same, so I was thinking if I put an `index.php` in the gallery folder and called it with a path and have it return a file list back to my JavaScript and a lough it to carry on.

How would I go about this as I am not very good with PHP at the moment? Thanks.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
      var dir_path = $(this).data("albumid");
      LoadGallery(dir_path);
      return false;
    });
  });

function LoadGallery(dir_path) {
  $.ajax({
    url: dir_path,
    success: function(data) {

      $(".image-container").empty();

      $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg), a:contains(.png), a:contains(.jpeg)").each(function() {
        this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
        var file = dir_path + $(this).text();
        $(".image-container").append($("<a href='javascript:;' class='thumb' data-src='" + file + "'><img src='" + file + "' title='Click to enlarge' alt='#'/></a>"));

        if ($(".image-container").children("a").length === 30) {
          return false;
        }
      });

      $(".image-container").append("<strong><p>Click on a thumb nail to show a larger image.</p></strong>");

      $(".thumb").bind('click', function() {
        var Popup = "<div class='bg'></div>" + "<div class='wrapper'><img src='<img src=''/>" + "<label href='javascript:;' class='prev-image'>«</label><label href='javascript:;' class='next-image'>»</label><a href='javascript:;' class='close' title='Close'>Close</a>";
        var Img = $(this).attr("data-src");
        $("body").prepend(Popup);
        $(".bg").height($(window).height() * 4);
        $(".wrapper img").attr("src", Img);

        $(".prev-image").bind('click', function() {
          var prev = $(".image-container").find("img[src='" + Img + "']").parent().prev('a').find("img").attr('src');
          if (!prev || prev.length === 0)
            return false;
          else {
            $(".wrapper img").attr("src", prev);
            Img = prev;
          }
        });

        $(".next-image").bind('click', function() {
          var next = $(".image-container").find("img[src='" + Img + "']").parent().next('a').find("img").attr('src');
          if (!next || next.length === 0)
            return false;
          else {
            $(".wrapper img").attr("src", next);
            Img = next;
          }
        });

        $(".close").bind('click', function() {
          $(this).siblings("img").attr("src", "")
            .closest(".wrapper").remove();
          $(".bg").remove();
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I also faced the same issue while shifting from local to remote. Check for the folder and file name Cases. In remote sometimes Apache is case sensitive

Comment: I have been on this some time now, and have spoken to the host company and they don't allow directory searching and they don't like .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

**Original** why *are* you getting the 403 error? returning a file(name) list from php to your scripts probably isn't going to work around this error, because the javascript would ultimately be making the same request.

on the other hand if you know that you have access to the image files from the server-side there are a few things you could do, like return the binary value of the image (javascript can take this) or generating a close of the file.

**Update**
if the server allows it, you can use the exec command in php to return a list of files from the directory: eg 
    \<\

```html
<?php
    jpgs = exec('ls /your_directory_here');
    echo json_encode(jpgs);
?>
```

if they don't allow exec(), which they might not, you could try...
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_directory_readdir.asp

does that help?

Comment: It is because you can't do directory searching, you must have an html or php in that folder, they told me to create a redirect script to make it work and this is my idea!

Comment: Any idea how i can adapt my code as at the moment it search's through the directory, any help here would be great, thanks.

Comment: In the ajax call where you currently call dir_path, you're going to want to call your php page. It looks like you're currently getting a formatted html page, which is actually more complicated to parse that what you could get from php..so you've got two choice